# Upload Image to s3bucket using front end as vuejs and backend as c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

I am passing

```
Logo = event.target.files[0]
```

this value of input file from my vuejs to backened.
On my backend C# ASP.NET
i am trying to get the value by

```
IFormCollection Logo
```

I don't know whether it is write method to send/recieve the file or I am sending right data or not.
The problem is I really dont know how to recieve the file in C# and send it to s3 bucket.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: yes asp.net core as backend !

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared much code with your attempt so I will give you a generic answer to work through.

You can upload your files to ASP.NET Core by following this guide [Upload files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

If you do this, you will use the [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-6.0) interface, which has the `OpenReadStream()` method.

You can then use the `TransferUtility` [Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility_Upload_1.htm) method in the AWS SDK for .NET by passing the stream that you got from `OpenReadStream()`.